# How to download Flickr Photos in bulk?

Tags: flickr

What is the best option to download Flickr photos? Now that Flickr announced of going away with Free accounts (limited to 1000 photos only),I would like to close their account. However, I have around 52,000 photos in my Flickr account and would like to download all my photos in original size.

I have tried [Bulkr](http://getbulkr.com/), but they have a limit of 500 photos.

What is the best tool to download all the pictures in a single click?

FYI - https://blog.flickr.net/en/2018/11/01/changing-flickr-free-accounts-1000-photos

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I tried Bulkr but its limiting to 500 photos per batch !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flickr has its own tool to export all your account data. [This article on Macworld](https://www.macworld.com/article/3153944/photography/how-to-download-your-flickr-photo-library-and-transfer-it-to-google-photos-or-icloud-photo-library.html) explains the steps you need to take.
I've quoted them below:

> 1.Log into Flickr via the web. (The Yahoo login account requirement is going away soon, too.)
>   2.Click the account avatar in the upper-right corner, and select Settings.
>   3.In the bottom panel, “Your Flickr Data,” click Request Flickr Data

As pointed out in the comments, the above method would leave you with a large number of .zip files to download when you have 52k photos.
The java command line utility [flickrdownload](https://github.com/masneyb/flickrdownload) might be a solution there, as it

> allows you to download all of your photos and the associated metadata from Flickr

I don't have a Flickr account, so I can't test, but it appears that with just two commands (one to authenticate, one to download the photos) you can download your whole library.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question, "What is the best tool to download all the pictures in a **single click**?" At the Macworld article, the screenshot shows 24 `.zip` files to download. The OP, with over 520k images, will have to download 1,040 `.zip` files. OP is asking if there's a tool that grab all those compressed files in one (or at least very few) go.

Comment: Fair point, I'll look into an edit later today.

Comment: =) oops... just to be accurate, I meant to say OP has **52,000**, not 520k images. So that’s only ~104 `.zip` files to download. Annoying, but doable in 30 minutes, unlike **1000** `.zip`s to download.

Comment: Alright, was able to follow the steps for requesting the Flickr Data, and it took almost 15+ hours to get the zip links. Here is a screenshot. 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr6K6.png

Also, I was able to find this alternative tool https://flickrdownloadr.com. FlickrDownloadr has options to download each individual Album or all Albums at a single go. As I had 50k+ photos in total, one of the album had almost 20k+ photos which failed to download. I will download the zips using Flickr for now. 

Thanks for helping out !